# Are Android Service instances reused?

Tags: android, android-service

Is a new instance of a `Service` created each time the service is triggered, or are instances re-used?  E.g. multiple calls to:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

---

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) imply that service classes can be re-used:

> If someone calls `Context.startService()` then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its `onCreate()` method if needed)

However, I cannot find this issue addressed directly anywhere.

Comment: "Is a new instance of a Service created each time the service is run, or are instances re-used?" -- that would depend entirely on what "run" means to you. You might wish to edit your question and use more precise terms, or describe actual scenarios (e.g., sequence of method calls and other events).

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once a service is started via `startService()` it is considered to be running. It remains in that state until:

- something calls `stopService()`
- the service calls `stopSelf()`
- the process is terminated (e.g., Force Stop in Settings)

While running, subsequent calls to `startService()`, for the same service class, go to the same instance.

Bear in mind that `Service` subclasses that you use may call `stopSelf()`. For example, `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()` if, after calling your `onHandleIntent()`, there is no more work to be done for that service (i.e., nobody else has called `startService()` to send a fresh command in the interim).

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful answer.  Do subsequent calls to `startService()` trigger corresponding calls to `onStartCommand()`?

Comment: @Armand: Yes. The *first* `startService()` call triggers `onCreate()`, followed by `onStartCommand()`. Second and subsequent `startService()` calls, while the service is running, just trigger `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: One other point: Services are basically singletons. There is only ever one instance of a given `Service` active at any given time (with a few minor exceptions in older versions of Android - this is basically an OS bug because it shouldn't happen).